# how to mount ZFS with mfsbsd

Tags: zfs

We need to mount zfs under mfsbsd to correct some scripts.
**zfs mount -a** does nothing, **zfs list** the same. **zpool** shows two hard drives.
Would be nice if someone could help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the OS you are running, you need to import a pool then file systems inside it will be mounted automatically (unless specific configuration).

Run first **zpool import** to get the list of pools available on connected devices then **zpool import *poolname***.

Comment: Then feel free to vote up my reply or mark it as an accepted answer ! Thanks.